# GitHub won't let me fork Hivemind, maybe something about sidechain repos

Tags: hive, project-fork

On [my GitHub page](https://github.com/s-matthew-english) I have a fork of `bitcoin/bitcoin`.

The project [Hivemind](http://bitcoinhivemind.com/) seems interesting, and I want to check it out.

When I try to fork it GitHub tells me that I already have a fork of it, and it references `s-matthew-english/bitcoin`, which is my fork of `bitcoin/bitcoin`.

Why is this happening? How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to fork bitcoin-hivemind/hivemind, which is a fork of truthcoin/truthcoin-cpp, which is itself a fork of bitcoin/bitcoin. So, your hivemind repository would end up being a fork of Bitcoin too, which is not allowed due to a [GitHub limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338240/how-can-i-fork-the-original-repo-when-ive-already-forked-a-different-fork).

The various workarounds suggested in the Stackoverflow page include:

- Creating an organization to fork hivemind
- Creating a second GitHub account
- Deleting the bitcoin fork, forking hivemind, and creating a bitcoin branch that is even with bitcoin/bitcoin. That way you can still make pull requests to Bitcoin, as that repository is still in the fork graph of bitcoin/bitcoin.

Comment: So then no one who maintains a fork of `bitcoin/bitcoin` can simultaneously maintain a fork of `hivemind` on their account?

Comment: @s.matthew.english: No, you could do that with a variation of the third suggestion provided here: A repository can manage multiple branches of the same code. You could check out hivemind into a new branch of the bitcoin repository.